# Как использовать цикл for in для массива из инициализатора класса?

Tags: ios, swift

Не получается вывести в консоль "Hello from ship - (submarine.nameOfShip)" от каждого элемента массива. Выводит только Hello from ship -

```
class Sailor {
    var name:String
    init (name:String) {
        self.name = ""
    }
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
class Ship {
    var nameOfShip:String
    var sailors = [Sailor]()
    init (nameOfShip:String,sailors:[Sailor]) {
        self.nameOfShip = ""
        self.sailors = []
    } 
}

let sailor1 = Sailor(name: "John")
let sailor2 = Sailor(name: "Paul")
let sailorsArray = [sailor1,sailor2]
var submarine = Ship(nameOfShip: "Submarine", sailors:sailorsArray)
for i in sailorsArray {
    print("Hello from ship - \(submarine.nameOfShip)")
    }
```

Comment: так у вас для каждого имени пустая строка присваивается в конструкторе, нужно делать типа такого - `self.name = name` в чем тогда смысл передавать параметр в конструктор если его не использовать потом?

Comment: Да, теперь вижу, в чем ошибка. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге как-то так должно быть:

```
import Foundation

class Sailor {
    var name:String
    init (name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
class Ship {
    var nameOfShip:String
    var sailors = [Sailor]()
    init (nameOfShip:String,sailors:[Sailor]) {
        self.nameOfShip = nameOfShip
        self.sailors = sailors
    } 
}

let sailor1 = Sailor(name: "John")
let sailor2 = Sailor(name: "Paul")
let sailorsArray = [sailor1,sailor2]
var submarine = Ship(nameOfShip: "Submarine", sailors:sailorsArray)
for sailor in submarine.sailors {
    print("Hello from ship - \(sailor.name)")
}
```

и вывод будет таким:

```
Hello from ship - John
Hello from ship - Paul
```